# Doubt in proving homomorphism from $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

My question is :

Let us assume that we have to find the number of homomorphisms from $S_n \to D_{2n}$ when $n > 3$

> How  to prove  that the elements of the form $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ always belong to the kernel.

So  all the even number of $2$-cycles can be written in the form $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ and they belong to the kernel. [which is what I know as $A_n$ is the only normal subgroup of $ S_n$ except when $n \ne 4$,but I can't use this result as I will have to prove this using sylows theorem which we haven't been taught so can't be used in exam ]

Comment: (i) Just to be clear, is $D_{2n}$ the dihedral group of order $2n$? [Some people use the symbol for the one of order $4n$.] (ii) What you say is false for $n=3$. (iii) In the final paragraph do you mean "Any product of an even number of $2$-cycles is (? a product of elements) of this form? (iv) There are  proofs that $A_n$ is the only proper non-trivial normal subgroup of $S_n$ which don't use Sylow.

Comment: 1)$D_2n$ is the group of order $2n$. 2) when $n=3$ it is isomorphic (3) any two cycle of the form $(ab)(cd)=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$

Comment: Yes, so the result is wrong when $n=3$.

Comment: Do you have any help as to how I am going to see the result when $n \ne 3$.

Comment: Well when $n$ is odd the permutation $(ab)(cd)$ maps to the product of two commuting elements of order $1$ or $2$, and also it maps to a product of conjugate elements, so either both map to the identity or both map to the same involution. Hence the homomorphism is either trivial or takes *every* transposition to the same involution   $\tau$ and we now know everything.

Comment: And essentially the same argument will deal with $n$ even (still $n> 4$) once you establish the conjugacy classes of involutions in $D_{2n}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician thank you for the answer that was what I was precisely looking for.

Comment: I have one doubt in my mind if f(ab)f(cd)f(ab)=f(cd).How can we conclude that f(ab)=f(cd)?

Comment: Look at the commuting involutions in $D_{2n}$.

Comment: I was just wondering if $\varphi(ab)-> s $ and $\varphi(cd)-> sr^{n/2}$.Then $s.sr^{n/2}=sr^{n/2}s$, and both of them are of order $2$.This can hold true when $n$ is even though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really like @ancientmathematician's argument above but if you want here's another argument.

Suppose $N$ is the kernel of your homomorphism, then $N$ has index dividing $2n$, so all $2n$th powers are in $N$, in particular, those elements whose order is coprime to $2n$ are in $N$. Now choose odd number $k\leq n$ coprime to $2n$ (the only time you can't do this is when $n=3$ which as the others mentioned is a counterexample, otherwise choose $k=n-1$ or $n-2$ works) then all $k$-cycles by the above are in $N$.

All $k$-cycles for $k$ odd generate $A_n$ so $A_n\subset N$. If you don't yet know this see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/what-do-all-the-k-cycles-in-s-n-generate) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3890223/645436) And it's clear that all commutators are in $A_n$.